# Django inline add ''clients.Client' has no ForeignKey to 'claims.Claim''

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add an inline add to my CreateView. Just like how it works in admin. I am getting 'clients.Client' has no ForeignKey to 'claims.Claim'. This is my first attempt at this so followed a guide online. I have also tried to use crispy forms to handle the template render of the forms.

**EDIT:**

A couple of people have mentioned that i need to switch the ForeignKey around. The way it is, admin gets it right, there is an inline add on the claim.

models.py

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)

class Client(models.Model):
    ...
```

forms.py

```
class ClaimForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Claim
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        exclude = ('creation', 'last_modified')

ClientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Claim, Client)
```

views.py

```
class ClaimCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ClaimForm
    model = Claim
    success_url = '/claims/list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClaimCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = ClientFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = ClientFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())  
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                            {% crispy formset formset.form.helper %}
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                            <a href="{% url 'claims' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ClientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, Claim)
```

Comment: How come in admin i get the inline add on the claim, which is the way I want it to be. If I move the ForeignKey to the client it will be the wrong way around

Answer (score 0):

The inline model should be having a ForeinKey to the parent model.